# Apache Subversion on Windows 8

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have been trying to checkout a code from a subversion repository on windows 8. I tried Apache Subversion client as well as TortoriseSVN client.

tortoiseSVN takes forever to checkout the code. Subversion fails with following error upon cntrl + C

> svn: E200015: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2' svn: E200015: Caught
>   signal

As an example I am trying to checkout code from https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/checkout.

Am I missing something? Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. I was able to download the read-only copy of the code locally. But I had to use CodePlexSVN. I found this tool us. [Here](http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/) is the link to download it.

Answer (score 0):

This repo is read-only, try this:

```
 svn://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/
```

Comment: Readonly? I am just trying to get the latest revision. I don't intend to make any changes.